# Question on product measure: $\int_{[0,R]^2} g(x,y) df_1(x) \times df_2(y) = \int_{[0,R]} \left( \int_{[0,R]} g(x,y) df_1(x) \right) df_2(y)$ holds?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose I have a real valued positive increasing functions $f_1(x), f_2(y)$.
Then we know we can define Riemann-Stieltjes integral by defining 
measures $df_1(x)$ and $df_2(y)$.

Let $g(x,y)$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $R>0$.
Let us define the product measure $df_1(t) \times df_2(t)$.
My question is the following.
Is it always the case that we have
$$
\int_{[0,R]^2} g(x,y) df_1(x) \times df_2(y) = \int_{[0,R]} \left( \int_{[0,R]} g(x,y) df_1(x) \right) df_2(y)?
$$

I feel like this should be true, but it is something I have never seen before... I would greatly appreciate if someone could provide me some explanation on why this would be the case? (or it's not ?)

Comment: Since $g$ is continuous on a compact set, we have $$\int_{[0,R]^2} |g|\ \mathsf d(f_1\times f_2)<\infty,$$ so Fubini's theorem implies that the iterated integrals exist and are equal to the double integral.

Comment: Right, of course! Thank you very much!!